# How to get jQuery's tokenInput plugin working with a <select multiple="multiple">?

Tags: jquery, select, input, token

I've applied the tokenInput plugin to a "multiple" select element. However, when I add multiple tokens and then submit the form, only last token's option value is sent. The document inspector in both Chrome and Firebug show that the 'selected="selected"' attributes are being properly applied and removed. I have the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link href="stylesheets/token-input.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="javascripts/jquery.tokeninput.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<head>
<body>
  <form action="" method="get">
    <select id="project_ids" multiple="multiple" name="project[ids][]">
      <option value="any">(Any)</option>
      <option value="blanks">(Blanks)</option>
      <option value="1">Project A</option>
      <option value="2">Project B</option>
      <option value="3">Project C</option></select>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </form>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      $("#project_ids").tokenInput(
        [{"id":"any","name":"&lt;Any&gt;"},{"id":"blanks","name":"&lt;Blanks&gt;"},{"id":1,"name":"Project A"},{"id":2,"name":"Project B"},{"id":3,"name":"Project C"}],
        {preventDuplicates: true,
         onAdd: function(item) { $(this).find('option[value="'+item.id+'"]').attr("selected",true); },
         onDelete: function(item) { $(this).find('option[value="'+item.id+'"]').attr("selected",false); }
        }
      );
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas on what I need to change? Thanks!

PS. [The tokenInput files are here.](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/)

Answer (score 0):

I recently wrote a module for drupal - though its still in sandbox.. Its for Drupal 7. You can clone and use it. http://drupal.org/sandbox/amrit_b/1420912